# user availability validations using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my availability form I am getting user availability with time and days like below:

```
<%= form_for(:Availability, :html => { :id => "availability" }) do |f| %>
    <table align="center" width="80%">
          <tr>
              <td width="13%">

              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="color:black; font-weight: bold;">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <%= f.check_box(:Monday,{:id => "Monday",:value => "Monday"}) %>
                    <%= label_tag "Monday" %>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div id="MondayDiv">
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <%= f.select :mondayFrom,options_for_select([
                          ["1","1"],
                        ["2","2"],
                          ["3","3"],
                          ["4","4"],
                        ["5","5"],
                        ["6","6"],
                        ["7","7"],
                        ["8","8"],
                        ["9","9"],
                        ["10","10"],
                        ["11","11"],
                        ["12","12"],
                     ]), {},:id => "DDL_TimeFromMon" %>

                    <%= f.select :ddl_MonFromAMPM ,options_for_select([["AM","AM"],["PM","PM"]]),{}, :id => "ddl_MonFromAMPM" %>

                    <%= label(:to, " to", {}, { :class => "labelTo" }) %>
                    <%= f.select :mondayTo,options_for_select([
                        ["1","1"],
                          ["2","2"],
                          ["3","3"],
                          ["4","4"],
                        ["5","5"],
                        ["6","6"],
                        ["7","7"],
                        ["8","8"],
                        ["9","9"],
                        ["10","10"],
                        ["11","11"],
                        ["12","12"],
                     ]), {},:id => "DDL_TimeToMon" %>

                     <%= f.select :ddl_MonToAMPM ,options_for_select([["AM","AM"],["PM","PM"]]), {}, :id => "ddl_MonToAMPM"  %>
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
    </table>
```

Its working fine but the problem is that if user check on monday checkbox and set time `from 1 AM to  1 AM` and it makes 25 hours and `from 1 AM to 12 PM` it makes 24 hours, so I want to apply validation using jquery if user enter `from 1 AM to  1 AM` and show error message that `Time From Should be less then Time To` and I am using below jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#availability").submit(function ( event ) {

    var monday_from = $('#DDL_TimeFromMon').val();
    var monday_to = $('#DDL_TimeToMon').val();
    var hasError = false;

    if(monday_from > monday_to){
        alert("Time From Should be less then Time To")
        hasError = true;
    }

    if(hasError){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

But its not showing me any error message, kindly help me waiting for you reply.
Thanks.

Comment: why you are checking the condition if((monday_from == 0) && (monday_to == 0)){ ??

Answer (score 0):

From you HTML, it seems that you don't have any option with value 0, yet are checking that condition in javascript, which returns false and if block never gets executed. Hence neither you will see any error nor you will get the expected result.